# What is the purpose of web.config files under Hive folder

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am new to SharePoint, I am using SP 2010. I am asp.net developer but I don't understand if I have web.config under 80, so what are those web.config files under 14 folder, can you briefly discuss it?

I found two so far, There is one under 14\Templates\Layouts and under 14\CONFIG

Thanks

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms460914.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint development is similar to ASP.NET development but there are some major differences you need to be aware of. One is the use of Web.config to store application settings.

I wrote a blog post with links to several resources to help new SharePoint developers get started: [Getting Started with SharePoint 2010 Development–Links and Resources](http://msmvps.com/blogs/windsor/archive/2011/08/01/getting-started-with-sharepoint-2010-development-links-and-resources.aspx)

I suggest you start by watching the [SharePoint for ASP.NET Developers](https://vimeo.com/29271944) talk to get an idea of the SharePoint architecture and development/deployment model.

Comment: Please take special note - you shouldn't modify the web.config files by hand (at least for production). If you use the SPWebConfigModification class to deploy changes, then the web.config files will be updated (and identical) across all the servers in your farm. Manual changes that are forgotten about (and later required when a new server is added) are a real pain.

Answer (score 0):

You will find a lot more in 14 hive :) They are there because they are web.config files for different parts of the entire sharepoint application pages. For example the one in "14\layouts\" is for general application pages, site settings, regional settings, ... for instance. the one in the 14\layouts\admin is for centeral administration pages.